# how to delete a specific row on gridview and ms access by clicking a button

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm new to C# and database so to practice I wrote a program to add to database, search ,and uppdate

the delete button works as follows; I search for the database element and if I succeed I delete that row..

now I want to click on a row, and delete it from the gridview and database
so

```
try
            {

                int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;


                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row);


            }
            catch (Exception )
            {

                MessageBox.Show("The Datatable is empty");
            }
```

this is how I delete it from the gridview, but I can't figure out how to delete it from the database, I'll appreciate if anyone can help, thanks

Comment: Is your gridview connected to a datasource?

Comment: yes, it's, all the buttons are working and this delete button too but with the above codes it only deletes from the gridview, I don't know what I should do so that it also deletes from the database